# Create Process Running Custom EXE file With Arguments

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I created a server class that requires a port input in order to start listening on the given port. I am now trying to implement a "Manager" class that creates more servers but I wanted to input the node parameter in the Manager console and have the server be created already listening in that given port.

The constructor of the Server class is Node(int port). (If this is of any help)

Comment: I don't get what you really want to do. For now, I think it's socket or something? (because you said `port`)

Comment: @SlaneR I want to create a process running my server (Node.exe) Once I do this, a console opens up (that is running my server program) and asks me for a port number. I don't want this to happen, I want to be able to start my server program from another process and give it the port number before starting in order to start with a port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server application have `Main` method which is entry point.

In this case, you can parse `args` to passed `port`.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    // no passed argument here
    // we can read port here
    if (args.Length == 0) {
        // Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // we can parse args[0] as int (port)
    else {
        if (!int.TryParse(args[0], out int port)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid port!");
            return;
        }

        // Node creation
        Node node = new Node(port);

        // Do something
    }
}
```

Let assume that your server application named `server.exe` then, you can passing port by `server.exe 1000`. In this case, args[0] will be "1000" (string, not integer).